# How to return observable with RxJS in proper format with additional separate paging data

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an API that returns the following:

```
{
  'data' : {
     players: [
        {id: 1, name: 'harry'},
        {id: 2, name: 'barry'} ...
     ],
  },
  'paging': {
    current: 1,
    totalPages: 10,
  } 
}
```

How do I return this correctly with players in the object and also paging info so they are separate keys?

```
getPlayers(type: string): Observable<Player[]> {
  return this.get(myApiURL).pipe(
    map(result => {
      'players': result.data.map(player => {
        player._dead = !!player.deathDate;
        return player;
      }),
    }
  );
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Interfaces**

```
interface Player {
  id;
  name;
}

interface Paging {
  current;
  totalPages
}

interface HttpPlayer  {
  data: {
    players: Player[]
  };
  paging: Paging;
}

interface UiPlayer {
  id;
  name;
  current;
  totalPages;
}
```

**Mapping to merge players and paging (regarding your question)**

```
const mergePlayersWithPaging = (data: HttpPlayer): UiPlayer [] => data.players.map(player => Object.assign({}, player, data.paging))
```

**Mapping to separate players and paging (regarding your comment)**

```
const mapHttpPlayerToPlayers = (httpPlayer: HttpPlayer): Player[] => httpPlayer.data.players;

const mapHttpPlayerToPaging = (httpPlayer: HttpPlayer):
```

**Use the mapping (merge)**

```
getPlayers(type: string): Observable<Player[]> {
 return this.get(myApiURL).pipe(
   map(mergePlayersWithPaging)
 )
}
```

**Use the mapping (separate)**

```
getPlayers(type: string): Observable<Player[]> {
 return this.get(myApiURL).pipe(
   map(mapHttpPlayerToPlayers)
 )
}

getPaging(type: string): Observable<Player[]> {
 return this.get(myApiURL).pipe(
   map(mapHttpPlayerToPaging)
 )
}
```

Comment: I adjusted the mappings.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem or do you need further informations?

Comment: I dont understand your issue with the above solution. No matter how many properties your object has. The mappinig either uses the spread operator that takes all properties or creates an object with object assign that also takes all params. Your main question was to fit the above interface structure.

Comment: If you feel there is a "cleaner" solution then maybe provide informations with what place you are not comfortable with. Also please focus on one question here and consider open another for further questions.

Comment: I updated my answer. Regarding to: "Doesn't it make more sense to send back an array of objects for players and a separate object just for paging". Your API already sends this structure. I am unsure what you try to achieve. I now answered your question and your new requirement (separate objects - regarding your comment). I will from now on stop updating now, because it seems that you do not know what you need/want. I tried to help you but the time i spend on this platform is limited.

Comment: FYI: This is more an JavaScript question than an RxJS question since it only regards to mapping.